# VHDL: Does VHDL allow enum to be passed to generic?

Tags: vhdl, generic

Is it true that one can pass boolean, integer and its subtypes as well as std_logic_vectors as generic to a VHDL entity?

Does this list also include enum types, which is user defined i.e describe an enum in package and then include it in the entity declaration and then declare a generic of that enum type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, yes, yes and yes :).

See for example our [PoC.io.uart.fifo](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/io/uart/uart_fifo.vhdl#L67) module:

```
entity uart_fifo is
  generic (
    -- Communication Parameters
    CLOCK_FREQ              : FREQ;
    BAUDRATE                : BAUD;
    ADD_INPUT_SYNCHRONIZERS : BOOLEAN    := TRUE;

    -- Buffer Dimensioning
    TX_MIN_DEPTH            : positive   := 16;
    TX_ESTATE_BITS          : natural    :=  0;
    RX_MIN_DEPTH            : positive   := 16;
    RX_FSTATE_BITS          : natural    :=  0;

    -- Flow Control
    FLOWCONTROL             : T_IO_UART_FLOWCONTROL_KIND   := UART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE;
    SWFC_XON_CHAR           : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"11";    -- ^Q
    SWFC_XON_TRIGGER        : real                         := 0.0625;
    SWFC_XOFF_CHAR          : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := x"13";    -- ^S
    SWFC_XOFF_TRIGGER       : real                         := 0.75
  );
  port (
    -- ...
  );
```

This module wraps a transmitter and receiver plus bit-clock generator in a single module and attaches two FIFOs. The module makes extensive use of generics in form of:

- standard types (BOOLEAN, POSITIVE, ...),
- physical types (FREQ, BAUD) and an
- enum (T_IO_UART_FLOWCONTROL_KIND).

The latter one is defined in the package [`PoC.uart`](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/io/uart/uart.pkg.vhdl), which is referenced by a `use` clause. The top-level module, that instantiates `uart_fifo`, needs also to reference this package.

```
package uart is
  type T_IO_UART_FLOWCONTROL_KIND is (
    UART_FLOWCONTROL_NONE,
    UART_FLOWCONTROL_XON_XOFF,
    UART_FLOWCONTROL_RTS_CTS,
    UART_FLOWCONTROL_RTR_CTS
  );

  constant C_IO_UART_TYPICAL_BAUDRATES : T_BAUDVEC := (
     0 =>    300 Bd,  1 =>    600 Bd,  2 =>   1200 Bd,  3 =>   1800 Bd,  4 =>   2400 Bd,
     5 =>   4000 Bd,  6 =>   4800 Bd,  7 =>   7200 Bd,  8 =>   9600 Bd,  9 =>  14400 Bd,
    10 =>  16000 Bd, 11 =>  19200 Bd, 12 =>  28800 Bd, 13 =>  38400 BD, 14 =>  51200 Bd,
    15 =>  56000 Bd, 16 =>  57600 Bd, 17 =>  64000 Bd, 18 =>  76800 Bd, 19 => 115200 Bd,
    20 => 128000 Bd, 21 => 153600 Bd, 22 => 230400 Bd, 23 => 250000 Bd, 24 => 256000 Bd,
    25 => 460800 Bd, 26 => 500000 Bd, 27 => 576000 Bd, 28 => 921600 Bd
  );

  function io_UART_IsTypicalBaudRate(br : BAUD) return BOOLEAN;
  -- ...
end package;
```

Comment: I see, so it is also possible to call functions from within the generic declaration, interesting,.